# Excluding page from Jekyll navigation bar

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I am setting up a basic Github-hosted Jekyll website (so minimal, I am not even bothering to change the default theme). I have a nested site with a small number of first-tier pages that I would like to appear in the navigation bar (i.e. the default mode of operation). I also have some second-tier pages that I would like to NOT junk up the navigation bar.

While a multi-level navigation system would be nice, I'm trying to avoid using plugins. Therefore, I believe the simplest solution is to just exclude tier two pages from the navigation system entirely.

Here's a hypothetical page structure (minus the other Jekyll files):

```
jekyllsite
jekyllsite/bar
jekyllsite/bar/alice
jekyllsite/bar/alice/index.md
jekyllsite/bar/bob
jekyllsite/bar/bob/index.md
jekyllsite/bar/index.md
jekyllsite/baz
jekyllsite/baz/index.md
jekyllsite/foo
jekyllsite/foo/eggs
jekyllsite/foo/eggs/index.md
jekyllsite/foo/index.md
jekyllsite/foo/spam
jekyllsite/foo/spam/index.md
jekyllsite/index.md
```

In descending order of awesome, this is how I'd like this to go down:

1. Best case, context sensitive navigation (don't think possible without plugins): When visiting jekyllsite/index.md, I would get a single layer navigation bar offering me links to foo, bar, and baz. When visiting jekyllsite/bar/index.md, I would see a two-tiered navigation bar containing foo, bar, and baz at the top level, and with alice and bob in the second tier.
2. The next best option would be for me to change something globally, such that only top-level directories (foo, bar, baz) got added to the nav bar. Subdirectories such as alice, bob, spam, and eggs would be automatically excluded from the nav bar.
3. Finally (and I think this might be the easiest) would be for a YAML frontmatter flag to exclude a page. Something like `nonav: true` in the frontmatter of the page to be excluded.

This seems like it would have to be a fairly common use case, though I haven't been able to find anything that looks like a short path to either of these three options. I'm hoping someone more familiar with Jekyll has a "path of least resistance" answer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It **is** possible to create a multi-level, context-sensitive navigation like you described without plugins, I have done it.

The only caveat is that you need to maintain a [YAML data file](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/datafiles/) with your menu hierarchy - with my approach, it's not possible to generate this automatically from your directory structure.

I'll show the short version here, but I have a way more detailed explanation on my blog:

- [Building a pseudo-dynamic tree menu with Jekyll](http://christianspecht.de/2014/06/18/building-a-pseudo-dynamic-tree-menu-with-jekyll/)
- [Example project on GitHub](https://github.com/christianspecht/code-examples/tree/master/jekyll-dynamic-menu)

---

### 1. Create a YAML data file (`/_data/menu.yml`) which contains your menu hierarchy:

```
- text: Home
  url: /
- text: First menu
  url: /first-menu/
  subitems:
    - text: First menu (sub)
      url: /first-menu/first-menu-sub/
      subitems:
        - text: First menu (sub-sub)
          url: /first-menu/first-menu-sub/first-menu-sub-sub/
- text: Second menu
  url: /second-menu/
  subitems:
    - text: Second menu (sub)
      url: /second-menu/second-menu-sub/
```

---

### 2. Create an [include file](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/templates/#includes) (`/_includes/nav.html`) with the following content:

```
{% assign navurl = page.url | remove: 'index.html' %}
<ul>
{% for item in include.nav %}
    <li>
        <a href="{{ item.url }}">
            {% if item.url == navurl %}
                <b>{{ item.text }}</b>
            {% else %}
                {{ item.text }}
            {% endif %}
        </a>
    </li>
    {% if item.subitems and navurl contains item.url %}
        {% include nav.html nav=item.subitems %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

This include file will take care of showing the correct navigation for each page:

- showing the next level of subitems only for the current page
- displaying the current page in bold

If you don't understand what exactly the include file is doing under the covers, read my [blog post](http://christianspecht.de/2014/06/18/building-a-pseudo-dynamic-tree-menu-with-jekyll/) - I explained it there, in great detail *(in the section "The recursive include file")*.

---

### 3. In your main [layout file](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/structure/), embed the include file:

```
{% include nav.html nav=site.data.menu %}
```

This will display the navigation there.
**Note that I'm passing the complete data file from step 1 to the include.**

---

### That's all!

As I said in the beginning:

The only disadvantage of this approach is that each time you create a new page, you **also** need to insert the page's title and URL into the data file.

But on the other hand, this makes it **very** easy to exclude some pages from the navigation: you just don't add them to the data file.

Answer (score 18):

I personally do ;

Front matter for page that appears in main menu

```
---
layout: default
title: Home
menu: main
weight: 10
---
```

Main menu template (classes are from twitter bootstrap) :

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  {% comment %}Jekyll can now sort on custom page key{% endcomment %}
  {% assign pages = site.pages | sort: 'weight' %} 
  {% for p in pages %}
    {% if p.menu == 'main' %}
      <li{% if p.url == page.url %} class="active"{% endif %}>
         <a href="{{ site.baseurl }}{{ p.url }}">{{ p.title }}</a>
      </li>
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

You can then replicate that at any level by setting a custom var in the yaml front matter :

```
menu : foo
```

and passing a value to a menu template

```
{% include navbar.html  menuLevel="foo" %}
```

And intercept it like this :

```
{% if p.menu == menuLevel %}
```

Any page that doesn't expose a **menu: toto** will not appear in navigation.

Comment: I found this solution to be very easy. Works for me!

Answer (score 18):

If you are coming from the basic Jekyll theme, the simplest way to exclude pages from the header site navigation is to add an `unless page.exclude` exception.

(`page.exclude` is a new Yaml frontmatter attribute.)

By default, this is in `_includes/header.html`:

```html
{% for page in site.pages %}
    {% unless page.exclude %}
       {% if page.title %}
         <a class="page-link" href="{{ page.url | prepend: site.baseurl }}">{{ page.title }}</a>
       {% endif %}
    {% endunless %}
{% endfor %}
```

and a corresponding tag to the Yaml frontmatter of any page:

```
---
... other attributes ...
exclude: true
---
```

Credit to [Michael Chadwick](http://codana.me/2014/06/16/excluding-pages-from-top-navigation-in-jekyll/).

Answer (score 0):

In _pages > blog.md.you can set nav:false.

---

layout: default
permalink: /blog/
title: blog
nav: false