# Hide a page in Jekyll website served by GitHub

Tags: jekyll

How do I hide a page in Jekyll? I have a Contact Us page (as a Google Docs form), and there is a response page. When created, it shows up in the navigation as a child of the Contact Us page, but I don't want it to show up at all.

I currently have this set up in the front matter like this:

```
---
layout: page
title: Thanks
permalink: /contact/thanks/
---
```

Answer (score 21):

If you do not put any title in the page, it does not show up in the nav bar. Something like

```
---
layout: page
permalink: /contact/thanks/
---
```

Comment: This is the correct answer for those using Jekyll for Github Pages.

Answer (score 15):

Rather than 'opting out' of including certain pages, you can 'opt in' to include only the pages you *do* want included in your navigation. This is useful if you have a large number of pages.

Include a `menu` variable in the front matter of every page you **do** want included in the navigation:

```
---
layout: blog
title: Blog
menu: main
permalink: /blog/
---
```

And then add an **if statement** where your navigation is generated:

```
<ul>
  {% for page in site.pages %}
    {% if page.menu == 'main' %}
      <li><a href="{{ page.url | prepend: site.baseurl }}">{{ page.title }}</a></li>
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

This is likely to be in `_layouts/default.html` or possibly `_includes/header.html`.

Thanks to David Jaquel's answer on this question for the inspiration: [Excluding page from Jekyll navigation bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25452429/excluding-page-from-jekyll-navigation-bar)

Comment: How do you modify where the navigation is generated in a GITHUB PAGES setup?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, could you provide an example?

Comment: I've added where you find this.

Answer (score 5):

Just add a `show_in_nav: false` in you page front matter and in your navigation bar, do a :

```
<ul>
{% for p in pages %}
    {% unless show_in_nav == false %}
    <li><a href="{{ site.baseurl }}{{ p.url }}">{{ p.title }}</a></li>
    {% endunless %}
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

This will prevent your page from appearing in navigation bar.

Answer (score 5):

According to docs, set published to false in your front matter:

```
---
layout: post
title: Blogging Like a Hacker
published: false
---
```

[Front Matter](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/frontmatter/)

Comment: This is not the correct approach. This would not work for 404 page which you wouldn't want to see in the header, but still wanted it to be published.

Comment: I guess my solution is more appropriate for posts instead of pages. But the OP wants to hide a page and setting the predefined global variable `published: false` works. Besides, `title` is not a predefined variable in Jekyll (its custom) and your solution relies on checking to see if `title` exists in the front matter (`{% for my_page in site.pages %}` `{% if my_page.title %}`), unless that is how its handled in GitHub pages and that can't be changed.