# How to create a simple, hard-coded navigation bar in Jekyll?

Tags: jekyll

I'm generating a Jekyll site with a lot of pages. By default, all these pages are included in the menu.

[image: Screenshot]

I don't want the majority of these pages to appear in the navigation bar. I want only two of them to be there: a) `/rumerica/` and b) `/about/`.

I tried to use the approach from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25452429/excluding-page-from-jekyll-navigation-bar) and put the following file into `_data/menu.yaml` file:

```
- text: Home
  url: /
- text: Rumerica
  url: /rumerica/
- text: About
  url: /about/
```

But nothing changed. How can I make Jekyll render only two (static and hard-coded) menu items without using any plugins?

Notes: You can find the source code of my site (without the new changes) [here](https://github.com/fdrollig/fdrollig.github.io/tree/master).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that this feature has been added in scope of the following issue:

- [Issue 19: Ability to specify Pages in Header](https://github.com/jekyll/minima/issues/19)
- Commit [add `header_pages` config to link only specific files in header](https://github.com/Crunch09/minima/commit/3317fd6c3d2604f7d17dc892792c5b6158b6d650)
- [Pull request 52: add `header_pages` config to link only specific files in header](https://github.com/jekyll/minima/pull/52)

In order to hard-code the list of pages to display in the navigation bar you need to add the following lines into `_config.yml` file:

```
header_pages:
  - rumerica/index.md
  - about.md
```