Excluding page(s) from Jekyll navigation bar when using minima theme
I am trying to implement the "add an unless page.exclude exception" solution found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32533975/8709901 so that I can limit the number of pages that show up in my navbar to just one (although I have dozens of pages in my site).
I am using the standard Jekyll minima theme, and the answer linked above suggests that the header.html is the place to customize, see: https://github.com/jekyll/minima/blob/master/_includes/header.html
How can I insert the {% unless page.exclude %} into minima's header.html nav bar build code?
I tried just dropping the suggested
{% for page in site.pages %}
    {% unless page.exclude %}
       {% if page.title %}
         <a class="page-link" href="{{ page.url | prepend: site.baseurl }}">{{ page.title }}</a>
       {% endif %}
    {% endunless %}
{% endfor %}

...into the header.html, but that just got me two nav menus.
